# Android: Open next activity after item clicked

Tags: android, listview, development-environment, listactivity

I'm new in android development.I just created the same app [using this code](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/)

After clicking on any item it shows the item name only on the next activity.What should i do to show some text, paragraphs and images in the next activity after clicking any specific item (like Adobe After Effects).

Comment: Need to make a layout file for your second activity.

Comment: tell us what you have done till now and in what part you are facing the problem? Also, read the blog post on "How do i ask a question" @http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey devil,thx for ur response.But i'm still confused.Is there any tutorial on net based on this....????

Answer (score 1):

Edit `single_list_item_view.xml` or edit `SingleListItem.java` file.
You can easily add texts or images by drag and drop method in  `single_list_item_view.xml` .